# Using $(this) in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is binding with JQuery datatable. There are 3 check boxes in each table/grid row- `Book`,`Modify`,`View`. My aim is to check the validation when saving the grid/table. If any of the row has all the 3 check boxes are unchecked, then I want to display validation message(i.e. checking at least one checkbox is mandatory). To check the validation I wrote the code below-

```
function Validate() {
    $(grid1.fnGetData()).each(function () {
        if ($(this).has('true')) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

`$(this)` have values like -

```
Book: false
ID: 945
Modify: false
Name: "ADGAS"
View: false
```

How can I re-write the code so that whenever `Book`,`Modify` and `View` have value `false`

PS: There can be multiple rows with all unchecked or mixed

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked fine for me -

```
function Validate() {
var allOk = true;
$(grid1).find("tbody tr").each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find($(':checkbox:not(:checked)')).length == 3) {
        allOk = false;
        return allOk;
    }
});
return allOk;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function Validate() {
    var allOk = true;

    $(grid1.fnGetData()).each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        if (!row.book && !row.Modify && !row.View)
        {
            allOk = false;    
        }

    });
    return alOk; // Make `Validate` return true only if all rows validate.
}
```

Comment: `if (!row.Book && !row.Modify && !row.View) ` is `true` even when `View: true` and `Book: false` and `Modify: false`

Comment: That is not true (no pun intended). Please read about the difference between `&&` (boolean `and`) and `||` (boolean `or`).

Comment: `$(grid1.fnGetData()).each(function ()` doesnt retunr the last added rows as rows are added dynamically. so I replaced it with `$(grid1).find("tbody tr").each(function ()` which doesn't execute your code. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !($(this).Book) && !($(this).Modify) && !($(this).View)) {
    alert("Validation error");
}
```

this assumes that $(this) is something like you said, which is unlikely, as pointed out by @undefined

Comment: That one message for each failing row in the grid, and still the Validate function returns nothing useful. And you refer to a deleted and probably incorrect comment.